# What is the easiest way to use python to read pureconfig config files created in scala?

Tags: python, scala, config, hocon, pureconfig

I have a scala config file created with the library [pureconfig](https://pureconfig.github.io/). I would like to write a wrapper in python to read and write this configfile (to give a better access to non scala users). Is the easiest way to parse the whole schema ?

My config file looks like:

```
tables = [
  {
    name = TABLE_1
    partition_strategy = "none"
    partitions = [
      {
        path = [
          "/shared/fall/raw/TABLE_1_2015.csv"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    name = TABLE_2
    partition_strategy = "none"
    partitions = [
      {
        path = [
          "/shared/fall/raw_data/TABLE_2_2015.csv"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    name = TABLE_3
    partition_strategy = "year"
    partition_column = "FLX_DIS_DTD"
    partitions = [
      {
        year = 2014
        path = [
          "/shared/fall/raw/2014_2016/PRODUCT/TABLE_3*2014.CSV",
          "/shared/fall/raw/2014_2016/PRODUCT/TABLE_3*2015.CSV",
        ]
      },
      {
        year = 2016
        path = [
          "/shared/fall/raw/2014_2016/PRODUCT/TABLE_3*2016.CSV",
          "/shared/fall/raw/2014_2016/PRODUCT/TABLE_3*2017.CSV",
        ]
      }


    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It looks that config syntax is actually HOCON (https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md). Perhaps you could try to use a hocon parser (e.g. https://github.com/chimpler/pyhocon) <I didn't tested that>

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thx !

Answer (score 0):

According to @mjjaniec: This syntax appears to be [HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md). You can use a Hocon parser like [PyHocon](https://github.com/chimpler/pyhocon)

This package also provides a conversion tool to convert from HOCON to the JSON, .properties and YAML formats.

```
usage: pyhocon [-h] [-i INPUT] [-o OUTPUT] [-f FORMAT] [-n INDENT] [-v]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help                 show this help message and exit
  -i INPUT, --input INPUT    input file
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT output file
  -c, --compact              compact format
  -f FORMAT, --format FORMAT output format: json, properties, yaml or hocon
  -n INDENT, --indent INDENT indentation step (default is 2)
  -v, --verbosity            increase output verbosity
```